# Profile is showing the question score for my answers, not the answer score

Tags: bug, status-completed

My profile seems to imply that one of my answers has a score of 47 and is accepted:
[image]

However, as much as I feel that my answer is worthy of lots of upvotes, my answer actually has a score of 12 and is unfortunately *not* accepted:
[image]

It turns out that 47 is actually the score of the question (*not* of my answer):
[image]

Comment: Does this happen with other Stacks you participate on? With other answers or just this one? To narrow it down and see if this is site-wide (and thus, more adequate to post in MSE)

Comment: Also, where are you looking at this? I am browsing your answers and I see the 12, not the 47 as your screenshot shows.

Comment: @DarkCygnus It's when I look at my answers on my own profile. It happens on other SE sites too evidently now that I check - I just happen to have seen it here first, so I posted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Exchange recently rolled out an update to the activity page across all SE sites. It looks like there are a few bugs with it, which are being tracked here:

[New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page)

If your issue isn't in that list then it might be worth reporting it.

Answer (score 3):

This has been reported previously, it is on [status-review](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review).

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been fixed in the latest round of changes on our Activity views.